# SQL (php) Need to Extract Best Records

Tags: php, sql, records

The following code is not working as it should.

```
SELECT Species, FishName, Rank, Angler, lb, oz, dr, Drams, Peg, DateCaught
FROM 
     (SELECT Species, FishName, Rank, Angler, lb, oz, dr, Drams, Peg, DateCaught 
      FROM   ConqPB 
      ORDER BY FishName, Drams DESC) a
WHERE Species = 'Common Bream' 
GROUP BY FishName 
ORDER BY Species ASC, Rank ASC, Drams ASC
```

It is a list for the species of Common Bream and will show a record list of the top weights for each fish name AND the angler that caught them.

BUT for some unknown reason - and I haven't edited it, it has stopped working and now only returns the one anglers best rather than the actual best.

The inner statement has tested fine and returns a list of the fish names and arranged the weight (drams) in desc order. When this is displayed then the top record of each fish name is the highest capture weight. The outer statement is now failing.

Any help here would be really appreciated. Also I would love to know why it stopped working.

An example:

```
Species           FishName               Drams             Angler  
Common Bream      Henry                  300               Peter Beard  
Common Bream      Henry                  400               Harry Web  
Common Bream      Henry                  0                 Carl Pilk  
Common Bream      Darcy                  0                 Peter Beard  
Common Bream      Darcy                  760               Harry Web  
Common Bream      Darcy                  900               Carl Pilk
```

The result would be

Common Bream Records

```
Fishname             Drams                 Angler  
Henry                400                   Harry Web  
Darcy                900                   Carl Pilk
```

Comment: Can you setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)? As for why it stopped working we cannot tell you. If it worked yesterday and doesn't today I would look at the raw data to make sure it hasn't been eliminated or changed somehow.

Comment: What's the point of the subquery? Why don't you just query `ConqPB` directly?

Comment: The data is fine. In the inner statement, it organises it as it should, but the outer statement is failing.

Comment: How would you go about querying ConqPB directly? Tried this before but was too complex - hence I asked on the forum before and this statement fixed the issue. Seems odd that it has failed. I have also messaged the hosting company to see if they have done something weird.

Comment: Added an example of what is required.

Comment: Just done a query in php to display the entire table and everything looks perfect. Just can't see why the code doesn't work no more :(

Comment: fancyPants has answered the issue - and so I will mark it off as solved because his solution does work as sql but not in a php statement where I think the issue might be server related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
*
from
t
inner join (
  select
  species, fishname, max(drams) as maxdrams
  from
  t
  group by species, fishname
) sq on t.species = sq.species and t.fishname = sq.fishname and sq.maxdrams = t.drams
```

- [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95e2f3/2/0)

Comment: This is what I don't understand. This code works as shown and perfectly but when it is used as a php script that is run on my site it is failing in every possible way - and this is also digging out only one name. I have checked the main table and all the info is present. So not sure why it won't work on the site. I've asked the hosts if they've changed anything because I haven't!!!

Comment: Is it possible that something has changed within the hosting site that could interfere in how my Sql is executed using a php script? fancyPants demo works brill but it will not work efficiently on my site. It still prints out only one anglers name.

Comment: I'm also certain that the Max function never works correctly within my php scripts.

Comment: Did you by any chance omit the `group by`?

Comment: It's intact. Just cut down the species to make it easier to see on the site and what is happening is I select a species and then your code executes but it is still only showing one anglers records and not the best. It's like the Max Drams is not working or something.

Comment: Getting weirder. I have another piece of code that checks for personal bests and also checks the current record. That query that checks the record is also not working.